# How to load obj model via three.dart?

Tags: object, canvas, model, webgl, dart

I need to load .obj file exported from blender on my Web app. But I'm not able to find a clear howto example. Example code is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three.dart does not have OBJLoader yet. But, it has an STLLoader which one can use to load STL models. The loader is not available in the pub.dartlang.org package as of today. You can get the latest vesions of the package on its [github](https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/blob/master/lib/src/loaders/stl_loader.dart) page. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/tree/master/example/web_gl_loader_stl).

Comment: three.dart now has an .obj loader (https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/blob/master/lib/src/loaders/obj_loader.dart). I have used it and haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a simple access to your filesystem while using dart on the client side. One option is to access the full blown html5 api's. That includes the FileAPI. The dart team realizes that this is a quite common request (load data into your application) so there is a pretty easy access to data you select via the browser (drag and drop of files is supported as well).

### 1) FileAPI

A pretty good example is hosted on the dart page itself:
https://www.dartlang.org/samples/dndfiles/

The source is available on github and shows you how to get a clear File handle after your data has been uploaded:
https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-samples/tree/master/web/html5/file/dndfiles

FYI: This all relies on the Window API (https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Window.html)

### 2) Chrome filesystem

When it comes to local storage you can also (try) to use the chrome api. This however, again, does not give you access  to the full file system but only a sandboxed local fs:
http://dart-gde.github.io/chrome_gen.dart/app/chrome.fileSystem.html

But before the question "can I access the data from my hard-drive with dart" comes up: Not easily. You can't do that while using your dart application inside the browser. This is forbidden by the browser itself. The only way around it is a native client extension (https://developers.google.com/native-client/pnacl-preview/nacl-and-pnacl). This is probably not what you want to do, though it is definitely possible.

Comment: ins0m thank you for taking the time to write this thorough answer. It's very helpful to learn how to access the filesystem on client-side. But actually that is not my question. Maybe my question was not clear enough. I want to load a 3d model (of any type) on webgel/html5 canvas. Three.dart is a powerful library for working with webgl. But I was not able to find examples on their website for loading 3d models onto canvas.

Comment: indeed, it read as i you had trouble with the fs. I'm sorry I cant help with three.dart